# Is there something wrong in my php and mysql program?

Tags: php, mysql

My codes is used to add some data to mysql. The name of the table is blog.The database contain four part.They are id|title|content|hits.
This is my codes.

```
<?php   
include("connect.php");  
    if(!empty($_POST['submit'])){  
    $title = $_POST['title'];  
    $content = $_POST['content'];  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `blog` VALUES(NULL,$title,$content,now())";  
    mysql_query($sql); 
    $er = mysql_error();
    echo"$er"; 
}
```

And this the error message:

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

So how can I debug it.

Comment: `INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')` basic syntax. Quote your string values also.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: `INSERT INTO table VALUES(…)` is a valid (shorter) syntax. But you are likely right that the missing quotes around string values mess things up here, if there is a comma in one of the values. Johann, on top of the quotes, you need to apply proper _escaping_ to the values you put into the query. And you should not use `mysql` functions any more, they are deprecated; use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @CBroe It's usually best to specify the columns into which they're being inserted into. But that's just me ;-) I like the extra work.

Comment: your error show that you have more than 4 columns in blog table and you are inserting only 4 values, you should have to insert values equals to your columns in table, otherwise you can try this it will do the job `INSERT INTO table SET a=1, b=2, c=3`

Comment: Mandatory finger-wag about using deprecated mysql functions and nudge to use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the error below often occurs when the columns you want to insert into are not specified.

```
Schema Creation Failed: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1:
```

Try specifying the columns explicitly.

```php
$sql = "INSERT INTO `blog` 
            (id  ,    title,    content,  hits) 
VALUES      (NULL, '$title', '$content', Now()) ";
```

Here is working **demo** of what I mean - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81fe7

If you comment out the columns and try and build schema, you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote your string values.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `blog` VALUES(NULL, '$title', '$content', now())";
```

Or even better:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `blog` VALUES(NULL, '".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($content)."', now())";
```

... to escape the values and avoid SQL errors or injections

Also, don't use old `mysql_` functions. Move to `mysqli` or even better `PDO` instead, and use prepared queries.

Comment: But why the error still exist？ count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Are you sure the table consists of 4 columns only?

Comment: sure，and the id will add one automatic，I am a fresh man,I am sorry.